My widget is disappearing, even though it is not Hidden
I'm trying to capture the mouse hover event on a button, to work on a image visualizer app. I'm using a standard QPushButton for it, and applying an eventFilter. But, when I install the eventFilter, the button disappears (it will capture the events, but the signal will not, besides it disappearing). I'm using PySide6
I will attach a snippet of my code:
class ImageViewer(QWidget, Ui_image_viewer_widget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.prev_pic_b.released.connect(self.prev_pic)
        self.next_pic_b.released.connect(self.next_pic)


        self.prev_pic_b.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_Hover)
        self.prev_pic_b.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.prev_pic_b.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        print("Event:" + str(event))
        return True


I'll also attach the images from my app before and after installing the filter:
Button before the filter
Button after the filter
Event filter working
I tried searching online for an answer, tried set the Hidden state to False(I checked the state, and it's False, as it should).

Returning True from an event filter means that the event is filtered, so it will never be handled by the object. Change to return super().eventFilter(obj, event) (object is a Python keyword, you should avoid using it, so change that also in the eventFilter definition).

It worked, thank you so much. If you answer the post, I will accept it as a solution. @musicamante

No need for another answer, as there already is a similar one. Besides, the installEventFilter() already explains how the filter should be used: "The eventFilter() function must return true if the event should be filtered, (i.e. stopped); otherwise it must return false."
